# Animate border when label value changed

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have these border and label:

```
<Border x:Name="PulseBoba" Width="auto" Height="auto" Background="#FFF75959" CornerRadius="2" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding kolicina}" FontSize="20" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Margin="5,0">
                                      <Label.Triggers>        
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">            
                <BeginStoryboard>                    
                    <Storyboard>                        
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"                             
                            From="0" 
                            To="360" 
                            Duration="0:0:2"/>                    
                    </Storyboard>                
                </BeginStoryboard>            
            </EventTrigger>    
        </Label.Triggers>

                                    </Label>

                                </Border>
```

In my vb.net code i have this piece of code which sets values correctly and displays in label:

```
...
 Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub
Public Property kolicina() As String
    Get
        Return m_kolicina
    End Get
    Set
        m_kolicina = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("kolicina")
    End Set
End Property
...
```

How would i animate this border to blink or rotate or any other animation when value of "kolicina" is changed?

Comment: For one, I see you are missing the `Storyboard.TargetName=`, add `Storyboard.TargetName="PulseBoba"`, but that is also if you are wanting to target the border, otherwise you need to add a name to the label... there are other issues as well... IMHO create a style you can use that targets either label and or border you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example bind the `Tag` property of the `Border` and use an `EventTrigger` that listens to the `Binding.SourceUpdated` attached event:

```
<Border x:Name="PulseBoba" Width="auto" Height="auto" Background="#FFF75959" CornerRadius="2" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Tag="{Binding kolicina, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
    </Border.RenderTransform>
    <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"                             
                            From="0" 
                            To="360" 
                            Duration="0:0:2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
    <Label Content="{Binding kolicina}" FontSize="20" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Margin="5,0" />
</Border>
```

If you require more control, you should implement the animation programmtically. You could then for example handle the `PropertyChanged` event of the view model in the view and create a `Storyboard` yourself in the code-behind based on any condition. This is a typical example of a case where it makes perfect sense to implement view-related stuff in the view.